# Can I have a webserver running IIS and Ruby on Rails on the same port?

Tags: iis, ruby-on-rails

I would like to know if Ruby and IIS 7 can live together, using the same 80 port in my webserver.

Answer (score 1):

Two disparate processes cannot share a port.  This comes down to basics of socket programming.  However, a sub-process can share a port with its parent, as seen with Apache on Windows (have a look using ProcessExplorer).

Comment: Pardon my possible ignorance, but isn't ruby just a programming language? If so, then it won't use a port but depends on whether there's a ruby module for IIS.

Comment: Just answering the ports bit.  Not a foggiest about Ruby.  Thought it was a semi-precious stone.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for this page?

[Ruby On Rails For IIS Fast-CGI](http://roriis.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is to run IIS on port 80, and use it as a proxy to the rails server running on a separate port behind it.

You would use a host-mask filter to do this.

Or, you could use IIS to serve rails directly via FastCGI, though I would honestly use something that is more "normal" in the rails world, and simply proxy it through IIS.

We do something similar with a Apache TomCat install running a java site side by side with .NET sites.